# How to do argmax in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Tried to search but did not find an `argmax` function. Are there any alternatives? Or am I required to write my own `argmax` function?

Comment: You can simulate it using a formula that combines MAX() and INDEX()/MATCH().

Comment: @ttarchala Could you provide a minimal example? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A simple formula simulates global argmax:

```
=match(max(<range>), <range>, 0)
```

To retrieve the max value itself, use index() with the above as an argument.

For a subset of local maxima of a range, probably a custom script function would have to be written.

[image]